# Is there a way to adjust contrast for Simple Scan?

Tags: scanner

Simple Scan works very well for basic day to day scanning; however, my scans are a bit washed out. Am wondering if there's way to adjust the contrast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple Scan 3.8** has available in Saucy Salamander, introducing various refinements and long-awaited features.

Navigating now to `Simple Scan-->Document-->Preferences`, summons the `Preferences` dialog containing the newly-implemented Brightness and Contrast additions.

[image: Simple Scan 3.8 settings for adjusting values for Brightness and Contrast]

Moreover, adjusting values for Brightness and Contrast is to be hassle-free performed via a draggable pointer, useful to increase and decrease the values per-user's likeness.

[Source Link](http://iloveubuntu.net/simple-scan-38-landed-saucy-brightness-and-contrast-support)

Comment: I fear this only works if your scanner supports it?

Answer (score 2):

Simple Scan is - by its name - simple.

There is this [outstanding bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-scan/+bug/669820) with a proposed pull-request.

However the main dev said:

> I'm a little worried about how consistent drivers are with these
>   settings, but I support the patch if it works. This setting will be
>   "advanced" as most users will adjust the brightness/contrast after the
>   scan is completed.

An alternative to Simple Scan is `xsane` from the software-center.

At first glance, it appears to be much more complex - however, its worth spending a small amount of time - it has great control over all aspects of scanning including contrast settings as shown.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. One of my scanner's (Plustek OpticSlim M12 Plus) is really finicky and Xscane didn't render pages properly. Simple Scan works well, just wanted to be able to adjust contrast.

Comment: both simple scan and xsane use the same sane backend.  Strange that xsane doesnt work.  There appears to be many front-ends - do any of them work for your particular scanner? http://www.sane-project.org/sane-frontends.html

Comment: In fact XSane is still a useful application in Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

Options I've found:

- Use xsane instead of simple-scan :-(

Xsane lets you adjust the gamma, brightness, contrast during the initial scan.

- Color calibrate your scanner

If you want to do it 'right' and, don't mind falling into time sinks, you want to import a 'color profile' for your scanner.  For that you need an `.icm` or `.icc` type file which is some processed output from a scan of a perfectly printed 'color target'.  In gnome 19.04 you'll find it under 'settings -> devices -> colour'.  Good luck finding one of those things to put through your scanner.

- Post-process your scans

imageMagick's `convert` program is very easy to use and will adjust various settings.  There is a fair bit of trial-error to get the right result. eg:

```
convert -contrast input.pdf output.pdf
convert -auto-gamma input.pnm output.pnm
convert -brightness-contrst -25 input.jpg output.jpg
```